# Failing to create catkin workspace

Tags: ros, gazebo, catkin-make, catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I tried to go through this tutorial [Tutorial: Using a URDF in Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_urdf) but I failed in the first steps. I gitcloned the RRbot stuff and tried catkin_make. But no success.
After this i tried to set up a complete new catkin workspace, just to make sure there is no error in my catkin workspace. But also with a new and plain catkin workspace it didnt work.

The error i get is here:

```
schultza@Andreas:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/schultza/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/schultza/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/schultza/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/schultza/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/schultza/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/schultza/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/schultza/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/schultza/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.9    
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library ... without any source files. This typically indicates a problem with your                CMakeLists.txt file
CMake Error: File /home/schultza/catkin_ws/src/package.xml does not exist.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/stamp.cmake:10 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:61 (stamp)
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:39 (_catkin_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:95 (catkin_package_xml)
  CMakeLists.txt:77 (catkin_package)


CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:112 (message):
  catkin_package() 'catkin' must be listed as a buildtool dependency in the
  package.xml
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:98 (_catkin_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:77 (catkin_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/schultza/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/schultza/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

Maybe someone of you can help me.
Im using ROS-indigo and Gazebo 2.2

---

Edit#1: Workspace structure

my workspace looks something like this:

```
catkin_ws
  build
  devel
  install
  src
    Package A
      (In almost every Package)
      include
      launch
      src
      worlds
      CMakeLists.txt
      package.xml
    Package B
    Package ....
    CMakeLists.txt
  RemoteSystemTempFiles
```

Sry for the bad formatting

---

Edit#2: Creating an empty workspace

```
schultza@Andreas:~$ source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
schultza@Andreas:~$ mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws2/src
schultza@Andreas:~$ cd ~/catkin_ws2/src/
schultza@Andreas:~/catkin_ws2/src$ catkin_init_workspace
Creating symlink "/home/schultza/catkin_ws2/src/CMakeLists.txt" pointing to                     "/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake"
schultza@Andreas:~/catkin_ws2/src$ cd ~/catkin_ws2
schultza@Andreas:~/catkin_ws2$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/schultza/catkin_ws2
Source space: /home/schultza/catkin_ws2/src
Build space: /home/schultza/catkin_ws2/build
Devel space: /home/schultza/catkin_ws2/devel
Install space: /home/schultza/catkin_ws2/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/schultza/catkin_ws2/src -    DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/schultza/catkin_ws2/devel -    DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/schultza/catkin_ws2/install" in "/home/schultza/catkin_ws2/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/schultza/catkin_ws2/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.6") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/schultza/catkin_ws2/build/test_results
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.9
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found PROTOBUF: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so  
CMake Error: File /home/schultza/catkin_ws2/src/package.xml does not exist.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/stamp.cmake:10 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:61 (stamp)
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:39 (_catkin_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:95 (catkin_package_xml)
  CMakeLists.txt:77 (catkin_package)    
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:112 (message):
 catkin_package() 'catkin' must be listed as a buildtool dependency in the
 package.xml
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
 /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:98 (_catkin_package)
 CMakeLists.txt:77 (catkin_package)
 -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
 See also "/home/schultza/catkin_ws2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
 See also "/home/schultza/catkin_ws2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
 Invoking "cmake" failed
```

---

Edit#3 CMakeLists.txt, maybe this could be also intresting

```
# toplevel CMakeLists.txt for a catkin workspace
# catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

set(CATKIN_TOPLEVEL TRUE)

# search for catkin within the workspace
set(_cmd "catkin_find_pkg" "catkin" "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
execute_process(COMMAND ${_cmd}
  RESULT_VARIABLE _res
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE _out
  ERROR_VARIABLE _err
  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
  ERROR_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)
if(NOT _res EQUAL 0 AND NOT _res EQUAL 2)
  # searching fot catkin resulted in an error
  string(REPLACE ";" " " _cmd_str "${_cmd}")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Search for 'catkin' in workspace failed (${_cmd_str}): ${_err}")
endif()

# include catkin from workspace or via find_package()
if(_res EQUAL 0)
  set(catkin_EXTRAS_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${_out}/cmake")
  # include all.cmake without add_subdirectory to let it operate in same scope
  include(${catkin_EXTRAS_DIR}/all.cmake NO_POLICY_SCOPE)
  add_subdirectory("${_out}")

else()
  # use either CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH explicitly passed to CMake as a command line argument
  # or CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH from the environment
  if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH)
    if(NOT "$ENV{CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}" STREQUAL "")
      string(REPLACE ":" ";" CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH $ENV{CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
    endif()
  endif()

  # list of catkin workspaces
  set(catkin_search_path "")
  foreach(path ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
    if(EXISTS "${path}/.catkin")
      list(FIND catkin_search_path ${path} _index)
      if(_index EQUAL -1)
        list(APPEND catkin_search_path ${path})
      endif()
    endif()
  endforeach()

  # search for catkin in all workspaces
  set(CATKIN_TOPLEVEL_FIND_PACKAGE TRUE)
  find_package(catkin QUIET
    NO_POLICY_SCOPE
    PATHS ${catkin_search_path}
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH)
  unset(CATKIN_TOPLEVEL_FIND_PACKAGE)

  if(NOT catkin_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "find_package(catkin) failed. catkin was neither found in the workspace nor in the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. One reason may be that no ROS setup.sh was sourced before.")
  endif()
endif()

project(YOURROBOT_gazebo_plugins)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  gazebo_ros
)

# Depend on system install of Gazebo
find_package(gazebo REQUIRED)

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GAZEBO_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDFormat_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Build whatever you need here
#add_library(...) # TODO

catkin_package(
    DEPENDS
      gazebo_ros
    CATKIN_DEPENDS
    INCLUDE_DIRS
    LIBRARIES
)

catkin_workspace()
```

---

Edit#4 After change my toplevel.cmake i got this output after trying catkin_make

```
schultza@Andreas:~$ cd ~/catkin_ws
schultza@Andreas:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/schultza/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/schultza/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/schultza/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/schultza/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/schultza/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/schultza/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/schultza/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _baxter_maintenance_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_TareEnable
Built target _baxter_maintenance_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_CalibrateArmData
[  0%] Built target _baxter_maintenance_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_TareData
[  0%] Built target _baxter_maintenance_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_UpdateSource
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target _baxter_maintenance_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_UpdateStatus
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target _baxter_maintenance_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_CalibrateArmEnable
[  0%] Built target _baxter_maintenance_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_UpdateSources
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_BatteryState
[  0%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PowerBoardState
[  0%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_AccelerometerState
[  0%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_AccessPoint
[  0%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PeriodicCmd
[  0%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_BatteryServer
[  0%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_SetLaserTrajCmd
[  0%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_BatteryServer2
[  0%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_BatteryState2
[  0%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_DashboardState
[  0%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PressureState
[  0%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PowerState
[  0%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GPUStatus
[  0%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_SetPeriodicCmd
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_LaserTrajCmd
Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_LaserScannerSignal
Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_AnalogIOState
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_CloseCamera
Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_EndEffectorCommand
[  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_CollisionDetectionState
[  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_DigitalIOStates
[  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_EndEffectorProperties
[  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_CameraControl
[  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RobustControllerStatus
[  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_AssemblyStates
[  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_SolvePositionIK
[  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_EndpointState
[  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ITBState
[  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_AnalogOutputCommand
[  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_EndpointStates
[  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_DigitalOutputCommand
[  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_NavigatorStates
[  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ListCameras
[  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_AssemblyState
[  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_HeadPanCommand
[  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_SEAJointState
[  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_NavigatorState
[  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_HeadState
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_CollisionAvoidanceState
Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_CameraSettings
[  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_OpenCamera
[  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ITBStates
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_EndEffectorState
Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_JointCommand
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_AnalogIOStates
Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_DigitalIOState
Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target add_two_ints_client
[  0%] Generating /home/schultza/catkin_ws/src/pr2_common-hydro-devel/pr2_description/meshes/gripper_v0/convex/l_finger.obj
/bin/sh: 1: ivcon: not found
make[2]: *** [/home/schultza/catkin_ws/src/pr2_common-hydro-devel/pr2_description/meshes/gripper_v0/convex/l_finger.obj] Error 127
make[1]: *** [pr2_common-hydro-devel/pr2_description/CMakeFiles/media_files.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[  0%] Built target gazebo_tutorials
[  0%] Built target _beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_Num
[  0%] Built target _beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_AddTwoInts
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188096/failing-to-create-catkin-workspace/) by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 232 on 2014-07-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-07-29**:\

> CMake Error: File /home/schultza/catkin_ws/src/package.xml does not exist.

This is strange: can you show us the layout of your workspace?

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2014-07-29**:
sry this didnt work see my main post

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-07-29**:
Did you follow these steps? http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2014-07-29**:
Yes, as I said i tried to create a complete new workspace (with this tutorial you posted) and the same error occured

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-07-29**:
So just creating (in a fresh shell) a directory structure like `catkin_ws/src`, then `cd catkin_ws` and `catkin_make` also doesn't work? So basically building an empty ws?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-07-29**:
Are you building from within eclipse? The `RemoteSystemTempFiles` seems to suggest you do.

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2014-07-29**:
I exactly tried to build an empty ws as you described above and it failed with same error. I tried once to use eclipse but didnt go further with it and stopped to use it, but it wasnt a problem times before

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-07-29**:
Ok that's strange. Please again create a fresh and empty workspace and post the output of the initial catkin_make.

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2014-07-29**:
Please see the edited post Edit#2

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-07-31**:
Has this been solved? Please mark the correct answer (@Williams) in that case.

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2014-07-31**:
Actually not really still having troubles as you can see in Edit#4

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-07-31**:
I remember that I had a similar problem with ivcon. Make sure it's installed AND added to your path.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-07-31**:
This has nothing to do with creating a catkin ws: ivcon is simply a dependency of the package that you're trying to build. Have you made sure you've installed all its dependencies (ie: used rosdep)?

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2014-07-31**:
Maybe a little comprehension question, if I want to use this robot from here https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_demos.git. I clone it in my workspace src folder and do a catkin_make. Or did i missunderstand smth? Do I need to call rosdep for dependencies?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-07-31**:
Yes, you have to make sure you have all dependencies installed. One way to do that would be to run rosdep. By hand is also possible, but is obviously more involved.

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2014-07-31**:
And how can I do this on the downloaded package? Can't find a tutorial for this situation.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-07-31**:
This can be found on nthe ROS cheat sheet: rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src       from your workspace root.

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2014-07-31**:
Oh god, i got it was a mistake in my workspace hierarchy -.- thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should never edit the boilerplate `toplevel.cmake` file. This code should be removed:

```
project(YOURROBOT_gazebo_plugins)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  gazebo_ros
)

# Depend on system install of Gazebo
find_package(gazebo REQUIRED)

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GAZEBO_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDFormat_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Build whatever you need here
#add_library(...) # TODO

catkin_package(
    DEPENDS
      gazebo_ros
    CATKIN_DEPENDS
    INCLUDE_DIRS
    LIBRARIES
)
```

If I am following your example correctly then that means you have actually edited the `toplevel.cmake` template file located at `/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake` and you should make sure you fix that one too.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2014-07-30**:
Hey thank you, it is still not working for my original workspace but if I create a new plain workspace it is! Please see my Edit#4 for the output while catkin_make of my original workspace

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2014-07-30**:
But i dont get it or I do something wrong... In here http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_overview they say i need to reconfigure my CMakeLists.txt, so I go to my current workspace in src and do it, but after this also my toplevel.cmake is reconfiguerd, where is the link between those?

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2014-07-30**:
So if I change the CMakeLists.txt in current workspace src folder also the toplevel.cmake changes

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-30**:
Yes - you should edit the CMakeLists.txt in your package - not the top-level CMakeLists.txt in your workspace. The top-level CMakeLists.txt is a symlink to toplevel.cmake, which is created by catkin the first time you run catkin_make.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-07-30**:
As a rule of thumb never edit anything under /opt/ros

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2014-07-30**:
Ok so it is menat to be that the toplevel.cmake changes within changing the CMakeLists.txt of my package?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-07-30**:
No: the catkin_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt *points* to /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake, they are the same file. You should edit the files in your own package, ie: catkin_ws/src/my_package/CMakeLists.txt. Perhaps http://www.nixtutor.com/freebsd/understanding-symbolic-links/ would help.

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2014-07-31**:
Actually that answer worked, there were just followed errors by an error in my workspace folders